# GIMP 2.8.22 font color rendering broken on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, gimp

[image: Screenshot]

This is not occurring in other programs like KolourPaint or Krita, and this was not occurring in Kubuntu 17.10. Also, even though the black text looks normal, I have noticed minute differences between it and text of the same size and font from 17.10.

Anyone know why this might be happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is due to [sub-pixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) used when it shouldn't. One way is to disable the SPR for your desktop, but [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195315) point to another method (not tested):

Create a `/etc/gimp/2.0/fonts.conf` with contents:

```
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="rgba" mode="assign">
      <const>none</const>
   </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: This got rid of the color corruption! Purportedly, this turns off GIMP's subpixel rendering. That may explain why text still doesn't seem identical (and worse) to text of the same font and size I rendered in GIMP on 17.10, but that's easier to ignore than the color artifacts.